# How to input data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I couldn't figure this out looking at other questions so I figured I would just ask. I'm really new to mysql so please don't laugh.
I'm creating at table named (department) which has its parameters set for the fields. I'm trying to load 5 rows of info into the field. I know how to do 1 row, but i'm confused on how to do 5. Any help?

Table example:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+
| dnumber | dname          | mgrssn    |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
|       1 | Headquarters   | 888665555 |
|       2 | Development    | NULL      |
|       3 | Sales          | NULL      |
|       4 | Administration | 987654321 |
|       5 | Research       | 333445555 |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You do each row step by step.

So like this:

```
INSERT INTO Department (dnumber, dname, mgrssn) VALUES (1, "Headquarters", 888665555), (2, "Development", NULL), (3, "Sales", NULL), (4, "Administration", 987654321), (5, "Research", 333445555);
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO sometable (col1,col2,col3)
 VALUES (1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good cheat sheet for SQL. If you need to load large amounts of data into a table you should look into writing stored procedures in C#.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: w3cshools isn't really reliable for anything, plus, there is nothing in that link that helps him with the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I thought this was an Sql Server question. Dont know what I was thinking.